# How to change the color of a word in a h2

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to have a word or group of word in a different color in a . This is the code I use:

```
<h2 class="text-blue">
    We are a <span class="text-orange">photography & video production</span>
    studio improving businesses &amp; brand's image and helping them to achieve their goals
</h2>
```

css:

```
.text-blue{
    color: #645f5f;
}

.text-orange{
    color: #ff8400;
}
```

My problem is that somehow the orange text appears smaller than the rest and not on the same line. Can someone tell me what I do wrong? Thank you very much[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDyxL.jpg)

Comment: Probably you have some other styles applied to `span` tag. You can check it in browser's developer console

Comment: You are right there a display:block and a font size specified. Should I use something different instead of span? like a div or a style?

Comment: Would a paragraph tag be more semantically correct for this content?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just add the font-size you want like this:

```
.text-orange {
font-size: 100% !important;
}
```

this will undo any predefined styles and make font-size 100%;
similarly you can add more styles with !important;

"If my answer is correct then please mark my answer as the right answer-> it will help my profile thanks Read: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers"

Answer (score 1):

That's a little strange...from what I can tell, span shouldn't really change the size of your text. I put it into Codepen as well, and I didn't really see any difference. However, if you really want to make sure, I recommend just manually adjusting the .text-orange class, so that the text is the same size as that of its parent class:

```
.text-orange{
  color: #ff8400;
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

Give that a try. Let me know if that works :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I used a div instead of the span and it solved the font size problem. However it is still displaying on a different line. any idea why?

Comment: div is not an inline element. if you just make it inline or float it, that should solve the new line problem

Comment: Hi and thanks again for helping me. You kind of lost me there though :) What do you mean by maiking it inline of float? you mean in my css class text-orange?

Comment: so there's a css property called 'display'. for divs, the default value for display is 'block', which means it pushes things off onto the next line. if you set the display as 'inline', it should stay on the same line. you can also use float: left, but that's a style difference. some people like it, others dont. doesn't matter, but just be consistent in using one or the other. but that's neither here nor there

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it thanks to you J. Zhou

I changed the span by a p and added a display:inline into my class. Following is the code:

```
    <h2 class="text-blue">We are a <p class="text-orange">photography & video production</p> studio improving businesses &amp; brand's image and helping them to achieve their goals</h2>
```

css:

```
    .text-orange{
color: #ff8400;
```

display:inline;
}

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that your `span` is being styled elsewhere, and it's receiving `display: block` - which is why it's breaking the line - and also a `font-size`. You can see it at the developer console.

If that's the case, then I highly suggest that you correct it instead of using  another tag, because `span` is the most adequate tag for inline style exceptions.

If you wish to keep that style, try changing its selector, making it more specific, so it doesn't affect all your `span` tags.

Comment: Hi Victor and thank you for your contribution. I tried to do what you suggested but I guess I'm doing it wrong as it breaks a line again. This is the code I used:

        <h2 class="text-blue">We are a <span class="text-orange">photography & video production</span> studio improving businesses &amp; brand's image and helping them to achieve their goals</h2>

css:

        .text-orange + span{
 color: #ff8400;
  display: inline;
}

I don't want to affect all my spans, that's why I chose to do that but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea why?